# Differences between JavaFx and JFrame in java

Tags: java, javafx, jframe

Hey what is the big difference between javaFX and JFrame, or are they the same?? I have not found anything on the internet.

Comment: They are not the same thing. They are two different APIs with different goals and ways of doing things

Comment: Can you explain what the differences are in does APIs? Why should i use JFrame or vice versa

Comment: You probably mean JavaFX's `Stage` and `JFrame`. JavaFX is an entire language.

Comment: JavaFX was slated as Flash competitor when it was first created, so it was focused on graphics and animation to start with. JavaFX 2 brought more form based elements (table in particular) and JavaFX 8 has brought 3D support (at least it's suppose to, but I've not looked into it). It uses a graph/scene node tree at its core, Swing uses a more canvas based approach. Swing has a customised look and feel, where as JavaFX uses CSS. JavaFX also has its own "fx xml" language (like Android) which can be used to describe the UI, before FX2, this was the only way to create a UI

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm

Comment: Try using a search like "difference between swing and javafx"in Google

Comment: There are tones of information around these like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Comment: I think that this question is wrong. It's hard to compare modern UI library to name of class in older UI library. You should learn more about UI's in Java.

Comment: @WonderWorld JavaFX is an entire API, Java is an entire language ;)

Answer (score 3):

Answer is very simple:

JavaFX is modern UI dedicated for Java.
JFrame is name of class in Swing (older) UI library also dedicated for Java.